# Inconsistencies in caret position, string length and matches index in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, caret, scintilla

I am trying to get the currently selected word in a Scintilla textbox using Regex, and I am noticing some inconsistencies between the reported string length, the matches index and the caret position or start of the selection:

```
private KeyValuePair<int, string> get_current_word()
{
    int cur_pos = scin_txt.Selection.Start;
    KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp_word = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0, "");
    MatchCollection words = Regex.Matches(scin_txt.Text, @"\b(?<word>\w+)\b");
    foreach (Match word in words)
    {
        int start = word.Index;
        int end = start + word.Length;
        if (start <= cur_pos && cur_pos <= end)
        {
            kvp_word = new KeyValuePair<int,string>(start, word.Value);
            break;
        }
    }
    return kvp_word;
}
```

In short, I am splitting the string in words and using the matches indexes to see if the caret is currently contained within the word.

Unfortunately, the numbers don't seem to match properly:

scin_txt contains the string:

> "Le clic droit a été désactivé pour cette image. J"

**This string is 49 characters long**, but the `TextLength` property returns **53** and the `Selection.Start` (or `Caret.Position`, same result) property returns **52**. The caret is at the last position in the string and there are (to my knowledge) no spaces or invisible characters after the letter "J".

Meanwhile the Regex match indexes and length seem correct.

Is this a bug or is there something I don't understand about how the lengths and selection indexes are computed? Is there a workaround to find the word containing the caret?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scintilla APIs are badly named. The `Text` property returns bytes, rather than text, and `TextLength` gives the number of bytes, not the number of characters.

Presumably, you are using UTF-8 mode, so the "text" is acually:

> Le clic droit a \xc3\xa9t\xc3\xa9 d\xc3\xa9sactiv\xc3\xa9 pour cette image. J

which is exactly 53 bytes long.

**EDIT**:

If you want to find the position of the start/end of a word, then there's the [SCI_WORDSTARTPOSITION / SCI_WORDENDPOSITION](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_WORDENDPOSITION) messages. For caret positioning, there's the [SCI_POSITIONBEFORE / SCI_POSITIONAFTER](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_POSITIONAFTER) messages, which take into account the current code-page. (Presumably these messages all have functional equivalents in the API of the particular Scintilla binding you are using - or perhaps some generic `SendMessage` function for accessing them).

Comment: Ah, that explains it. I though about something like that but I thought the text was in Unicode, not UTF8 and the results didn't make sense. Is there a simple way of knowing what the caret position is in the string, or another way of knowing what the current word is?

Comment: @Sylverdrag. Not sure about simple, but see my updated answer for some of the options.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it's pretty simple in .NET. I found a ".GetColumn(int)" method that converts the position to the text position.